# On a network with multiple pulseaudio servers, which configurations take effect?

Tags: linux, pulse-audio

I have a setup with several computers all running pulseaudio. Some act as "sinks", an are connected to the actual audio devices. There is one "hub" that has tunnels and a combine sink configured for all those; and the remaining are "sources" - they tunnel to the combined sink on the hub. Simplified, it looks like this:

- Machines A and B (sinks) have one sink each (A1 and B1), which are ALSA device sinks.
- Machine C (hub) has three sinks: C1 that tunnels to A1, C2 that tunnels to B1, and C3 that combines C1 and C2
- Machine D (source) has one sink D1, which is a tunnel to C3

I'm having trouble understanding which machines I should be configuring, and how the configurations interact with each other. For example, should I set the resampling method on the source, hub, or sinks? The problem I have at the moment is that the hub is sitting at 100% CPU usage and I am unable to bring it down.

I also have noticed that if I bypass the setup and play audio locally on one of the computers acting as sink, the output volume is MUCH higher, and I can't understand why - I checked volume settings on every machine's sinks and sink-inputs.